# Jabber auto-login with random name

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm building a live chat using [JSJaC](http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/) and [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) . It's all working except that all site visitors are given the account 'guest'. If two visitors try to livechat at the same time the responses get muddled or the first user is logged out.

I can randomly set the guest name but then I need to check whether that name is registered or auto-register and hope it hasn't been registered before. I tried assigning each login to a random resource name but this still merged the conversations.

In short i'm looking for the easiest way to allow multiple anonymous logins to start individual conversations with the livechat account. Even better (but optional) if the livechat could round-robin to a different user when the primary livechat account is in a chat.

The solution can be web-client or server based, I don't care since I control both (and ejabberd supports various modules).

BTW, when I try to auto-register a registered account the JSJaC simpleclient demo returns:

```
An error occured:
Code: 409
Type: cancel
Condition: conflict
```

I haven't established yet if this is something I can ignore or override with a custom client or server setup. I suppose I could just detect this error and try again without auto-register but I'd like to hear better/easier options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling [anonymous login mode](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Anonymous+users+support) on your ejabberd server? Then you don't have to register the client accounts, just pick any random username and password and ejabberd should accept them...

Comment: thank you, I was not sure such a thing existed. Sounds like exactly what I'm after.

Comment: oddly enough it doesn't work, though I followed the instructions to the letter (I get 401 not-authorised errors). I'll ask over at serverfault or the ejabberd but this answer is still acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use external authentication in ejabberd
I'm in the same situation: I want anonymous users to be able to login in the server, but some special users also be able to login for adiminstrative tasks...
So I decided to write a php script as an authentication handler for ejabberd.
Then it will accept all logins with the name starting with anon_*
and authenticate other users against a database.

Comment: It is possible in ejabberd to use both database login and anonymous login. You can have several auth_method referenced. In that case, order matters. Use the database auth first and then the anonymous one as fallback.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue in a project - we wanted users to be able to login without requiring any account creation or clashes - auto-registration would not work for us because names could clash.  In the end we chose anonymous login with SASL authentication in ejabberd - it allows anonymous login and dynamic account creation and I believe the accounts do not stay on the system (they are alive only whilst the connection is open), however from what I remember the server will generate a random ID for the user.

The GUID JID problem might be able to be solved with the use of [Nicknames](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html)

[Set up SASL](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/guide_en#saslanonymous)

[Ejabberd Support Page - SASL](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Anonymous+users+support)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get ejabberd's anonymous mode working, you might try creating a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid) for each user's base name, and just registering the user on the fly.  You'll want to have a periodic script that deletes old unused accounts from the database.

Comment: That's actually what I did in the end, though I used shorter names than a guid. It's too late to give you the answer though. I actually got anonymous mode working but it kept assigning GUID-like names instead of the one the user chose. The operators may be using PDAs/Iphones so I didn't want users like 2349823498328746873247565843@domain.com/help clogging up chat window realestate.